# Software with onscreen calendar notification on android?

Tags: android, calendar

On Android, I don't check my email regularly and would like to get a Google calendar notification five days before International women's day which I just missed and similar events. By I 21st it to be obvious I my android notification drawer. If I can have a pop-up like Facebook messenger for the ever that would be better because I often clear the drawer without looking.

So, sorry if this is not a separate question, but is there an app like Google calendar which displays conspicuous on-screen notifications like Facebook messenger for Valentine's, women's day, mothers day, fathers day, and others I might want to define?

Thanks.

Comment: For events I define, my calendar gives me a popup warning at the time defined (e.g. 2h before it happens) – and I have to press either the "dismiss" or the "snooze" button. Is that what you're after?